# CasperJS running not showing output to console

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm running Casperjs from the cmd, and while everything seems to work ok (the script runs as expected),
It won't show the `echo` command in the cmd without me pressing a key (`return`).

Here's the code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start('http://casperjs.org/');

casper.then(function() {
    this.echo('First Page: ' + this.getTitle());
});

casper.thenOpen('http://phantomjs.org', function() {
    this.echo('Second Page: ' + this.getTitle());
});

casper.run();
```

And here's an image of the problem (won't show anything without me pressing `return`):
[image]

After I hit return twice:
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a work around so to say...
I created a batch file and ran it and it worked.

I've created something like this:

```
echo Testing something...
casperjs test1.js
```